# How to set address lange limit on inbound firewall rule on Netgear DG834GU

Tags: firewall

In the firewall settings on a Netgear DG834GU modem/router I am trying to create an inbound rule that allows SMTP traffic (port 25) only from an address range (only allow mail from Postini anti-spam service).

Under WAN Users I select Address Range and enter start 74.125.148.0 and end 74.125.151.255.

An error appears when I try and save: "Invalid destination start ip, please enter again, Invalid finish ip, please enter again".

I also tried entering as an IP/subnet pair but same error.

Why wouldn't this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start 74.125.148.1 and end 74.125.151.254

Comment: Yes, that worked. And I feel like an idiot for not thinking of that myself. Thanks so much.

Comment: well I consider this a problem in the netgear interface... they should not assume 24bit netmasks for this application